# How to get only logged in user_id instead passing JWT AUTH Token everytime on APIs call

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I am developing APIs and I'm using JWT Auth Token when i logged in JWT gives me token and each time i passed this token on URL PRM on *Postman* so that i can add required data with logged in user id.

But i dont want to pass this token everytime this should pick user_id automatically when saving data and i dont need to pass token everytime when saving data into database against user_id.

This is my one of api call:

```
    public function addPage(Request $request)
     {
    $fieldsValidation = [

        'page_url'  =>  'required|unique:page_master,page_url',
        'page_name' => 'required',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $fieldsValidation);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $resultArray = [
            'status' => 0,
            'message' => $validator->errors()->first(),
            'dataArray' => []
        ];
    } else {

        $page = new Page($request->all());

        $user = User::find($request->user_id);
        $user->pageUrl()->save($page);

        $resultArray = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Page url added!', 'dataArray' => $page];
    }
    return Response::json($resultArray, 200);
}
```

if i dont pass the token it sayas call to member function pageurl() on null. its hurting me and i am using laravel 5.5. with JWT Auth package.
ANy help would be appreciated:

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing `user_id` then:

```
$user = User::find( $request->user_id);

$user->pageUrl()->save($page);
```